# No messages found in partition 0 at offset 0 Kafka kafdrop

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using kafdrop to view messages (MacOS catalina). I can see the partition 0 with offset 8 but when I click "View Message", it says "No message found for partition 0 at offset 0".

Any clue when I cannot see the message?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a problem of the new version of Kafdrop. I got the same with 3.25.0. 
Rollback to 3.23.0 helped, it displays my messages.

Comment: That's it, i switched to a lower version, e.g., 3.23 and all worked. The latest 3.26 seems having issues ( at least on Mac)

Comment: I have experienced the same situation for 3.27. I don't know the main reason.